# Double integral is not solved

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve the following double integral:

$$\int_{0}^k \int_{d+rk-rx}^s \frac{d-[(1-r)x+rk-c]}{ds^2} \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x $$

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(d - ((1 - r) x + r k - c))/(d s^2), {y, d + r k - r x, s}, {x, 0, k}], Assumptions -> s > 1 > d > k > 0 && 0 < r < 1]
```

The result it generates is

```
(k (-2 c - 2 d + k + k r) (d + k r - s - r x))/(2 d s^2)
```

However, this cannot be the solution since it contains $x$, which means that the integration w.r.t. $x$ was not conducted. Only when I do the integration one by one, do I get the right solution.

More specifically, the integration w.r.t. $y$ first:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(d - ((1 - r) x + r k - c))/(d s^2), {y, d + r k - r x, s}],Assumptions -> s > 1 > d > k > 0 && 0 < r < 1]
```

which yields:

```
-(((c + d - k r + (-1 + r) x) (d + k r - s - r x))/(d s^2))
```

Then, the integration w.r.t. $x$, using the above as the integrand:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[-(((c + d - k r + (-1 + r) x) (d + k r - s - r x))/(d s^2)), {x, 0, k}], Assumptions -> s > 1 > d > k > 0 && 0 < r < 1]
```

which yields the final solution:

```
(k (-6 d^2 - 3 c (2 d + k r - 2 s) + 3 d (k + 2 s) + k (k r (1 + 2 r) - 3 (1 + r) s)))/(6 d s^2)
```

Can anyone enlighten me why Mathematica couldn't solve the first double integral?

Comment: In multiple integrals the first variable given corresponds to the outermost integration and is the last integration done.  Since the $y$ integration was performed last and its upper limit contains $x$, the result contains $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(d - ((1 - r) x + r k - c))/(d s^2), {x, 0, k}, {y,d + r k - r x, s}], Assumptions -> s > 1 > d > k > 0 && 0 < r < 1]
(*(1/(6 d s^2))k (-6 d^2 - 3 c (2 d + k r - 2 s) + 3 d(k + 2 s) +k (k r (1 + 2 r) - 3 (1 + r) s))*)
```

lookup documentation "Multiple integrals use a variant of the standard iterator notation. The first variable given corresponds to the outermost integral and is done last."

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!